# Finding members who have been active 2 weeks(any 2) out of the last 4 weeks in SQL

Tags: python, sql, date, bigdata, amazon-athena

Hello good people of stack overflow

As the title says, I am trying to find the members who have been active 2 weeks(any 2) out of the last 4 weeks in my table.

For example, if a member is active in (week 1 and week 4) or (week 1 and week 3) or (week 2 and week 3 and week4) or (week 1 and week 2 and week3 and week 4) this should return me **1**. If the user is active in only 1 week out of the 4 weeks or not active at all then it should give me **0**. I hope that makes sense.

My table has an is_active flag which either says 'Y' or 'N'

My query right now goes as below:

```
SELECT count(Distinct(member_id)) FROM member_table where date > to_iso8601(current_date - interval '7' day) and is_active = 'Y';
```

The above query gives me the member count of people who have been active in the last week.

I can re run the query 4 times for different weeks, using some computing knowledge in Python, i will be able to reach my answer.
Instead, i want to find a solution using only SQL. In 1 query if it may be possible.

Please give me your opinion/suggestions on how to deal with this problem.

Help is extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "week" mean?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: week as in the last 7 days from current date - its in the query, i should have mentioned it in the question too.

Comment: Count the active weeks with a partition and then impose where count=2.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I am not sure what "week" means in this context.  You can count the days for each member using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.  If there is one day per week:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM member_table 
WHERE date > current_date - interval '28' day and
      is_active = 'Y'
GROUP BY member_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

If you simply need them to be active on two days that are at least a week apart:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM member_table 
WHERE date > current_date - interval '28' day and
      is_active = 'Y'
GROUP BY member_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 AND
       MAX(date) > MIN(date) + interval '7' day;
```